# Google Cloud Storage Ajax Request Not Working

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-cloud-platform, cors, google-cloud-storage

I have 2 files on google cloud storage: a.wav and b.txt

I want to play a.opus in my browser, which is working fine.
And I want to read b.txt

[Google Docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/cookie-based-authentication) tell that if the user is authenticated in the browser, he can download the object from bucket.

```
<audio
    controls
    src="https://storage.cloud.google.com/bucketPath/a.wav" type="audio/ogg; codecs=opus">
        Your browser does not support the
        <code>audio</code> element.
</audio>
```

This gets a.wav and plays it. No problem.

Now to read b.txt, I'm using jquery ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://storage.cloud.google.com/bucketPath/b.txt",
    type: "GET",
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    crossDomain: true
}).done(function (data) {
    console.log( data );
}).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
    alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus + " , " + errorThrown );
});
```

But this gives me error and following is printed in console:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://storage.cloud.google.com/bucketPath/b.txt'
>   from origin 'url' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

Also, in the Network tab, I can see that the wav file got response 206.

But for the txt file, I'm getting Status as `(canceled)`

Why does the Audio element work but ajax does not?

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, you need to modify the CORS configuration of the bucket where the files are stored. It needs an ['Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-origin-response-header), because same-origin policy applies when you make the request using jQuery. You can find more information about how CORS works with Cloud Storage [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin).

Follow [these steps](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/configuring-cors#troubleshooting) to make sure CORS requests to your bucket are not rejected.